# Working culture in the United States vs. Europe

Tags: united-states, europe

I work in a tourism office in Europe. When we complain about working conditions, our manager (who has worked in the US) says that Europe is like heaven for employees. I am not sure if he exaggerates to convince us or working in the US is that hard. He says, for example,

1. Here, employer cannot force us to work after working hours, but in the US, if you do not finish your project in due time, you will lose your job.
2. There is no official lunch time in the US. Here, we have about an hour.

What are the main differences in working conditions between the US and Europe (EU).

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: Made an edit that I hope will allow for reopening.

Comment: Some things like breaks and other “hard” aspects of working conditions are now regulated at the EU level, at least to some extent, but there are still very large cultural differences from one European country to another.

Comment: @DJClayworth While the edit does clarify the question, I think the new question is really too broad to be answered properly.

Comment: "When we complain about working conditions, our manager says that Europe is like heaven for employees." Well, what about your complaints? Does your manager do anything to get those addressed? The fact that there are bad companies in the U.S. which don't give you lunch, for example, probably doesn't solve your concerns.

Answer (score 5):

The guaranteed minimum standard for a worker in every country in the European Union (not Europe! Do not mix this up!) is:

- a limit to weekly working hours, which must not exceed 48 hours on average, including any overtime
- a minimum daily rest period of 11 consecutive hours in every 24
- a rest break during working hours if the worker is on duty for longer than 6 hours
- a minimum weekly rest period of 24 uninterrupted hours for each 7-day period, in addition to the 11 hours' daily rest
- paid annual leave of at least 4 weeks per year

There is no official lunch time in the US, there is no official lunch time in the EU either.

The minimum rights of the European Union and the federal law of the US are not even remotely sufficient to determine the workers rights and make a useful comparison, as each state in the US and each country in the EU have different laws which extend the minimum rights in one area or the other. For example, employees in California get a break after five hours of work, which is shorter than the 6 hours of the EU minimum standard.

Comparing your individual rights in whatever EU country you are, with the EU minimum conditions, there is a fair chance that your conditions are already better and there is no need to look at the US, but just look at an EU country with worse conditions than you have.

For amusement, you can look up the laws from the US state where he worked before and look for a right you don't have. For example, quite some US states offer short *paid* breaks. Next time he whines you can then ask for the US benefit to make him feel more like home. You should evaluate before if it's worth to be cheeky though.

Comment: "US employer must allow bona fide meal periods, which is a 30 minute or more break to eat a regular meal" Only in less than half of the states

Comment: @YviDe Thank you, I removed that part and made a different example.

Comment: It might be difficult to make a comparison, but I don't agree that the minimum requirements are not indicative.  For example, I wager most people would prefer to have paid vacation of 4 weeks a year versus none.  And states generally do not diverge from federal law on fundamental issues like vacation time (no state requires employers give employees paid vacation time).

Comment: You missed the most important thing which is that in most states of the US you can be fired at any time for almost any reason with no compensation.

Comment: @DJClayworth The European Union does not mandate a better system. Actually worse, they did officially declare in the _Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union_ that they will not set European dismissal standards. This is why I believe that comparing "EU" and "US" serves no purpose. You can compare European countries and states of the US. There are 28 countries in the EU - the working conditions in Germany and Latvia will already be dramatically different (this is a guess, I have no clue about Latvian laws).

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh That's true, but you can only get the whole package. If the 4 weeks paid vacation come in a package with taxes over a year that are higher than 4 weeks payment, the people who would want paid vacation might change their mind again. ;)

Comment: And I have seen a lot of US workers who don;t take a lunch period even though the company gives one so take that no lunch thing with a grain of salt. I have never worked anywhere that did not offer a lunch break .